# what is difference of (b*a)* and (ab*)*? Or they are same language?

Tags: regex

what is difference of `(b*a)*` and `(b*a)*?` Or they are same language?

Comment: Is the question mark meant to be part of the second regex? They're identical otherwise

Comment: my second one is (ab*)*

Comment: Not it's not. Edit your question.

Comment: If you actually meant the difference between `(b*a)*` and `(ab*)*`, try matching the strings `ab` and `ba` with them.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is a **greedy** matching (the asterisk quantifier after the scope) - matches as **many** characters as possible. The second one is a **lazy** matching (the asterisk and the question mark) of the **same** pattern. Lazy means to match as **little** as possible characters.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions

Your **greedy** expression (the first one) will match the first 4 characters in input `bbbac`. The **lazy** algorithm will simply match **nothing**, because zero length matching is the minimum allowed. Nothing here means an `epsilon`, and infinite number of epsilons are assumed to exist around every character.

If you translate these patterns to an ABNF grammar you get this:

```
main =  *(*"b" "a")
```

If you translate it to a language it is: [image]